# cpuinfo shows 40 vcores on 10 core processros

Tags: linux, cpu, centos-6

Recently I procured a machine with [Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/81705/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-v3-25M-Cache-2_30-GHz) with 128GB RAM running CentOS 6.7.
The specs in Intel web site show that this processor has 10 cores (20 hyper threaded cores).

However when the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows **this output 40 times** with processor number ranging from 0 to 39.

> processor : 0
>   vendor_id : GenuineIntel
>   cpu family    : 6
>   model     : 63
>   model name    : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz
>   stepping  : 2
>   microcode : 42
>   cpu MHz       : 2294.725
>   cache size    : 25600 KB
>   physical id   : 0
>   siblings  : 20
>   core id       : 0
>   cpu cores : 10
>   apicid        : 0
>   initial apicid    : 0
>   fpu       : yes
>   fpu_exception : yes
>   cpuid level   : 15
>   wp        : yes
>   flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
>   bogomips  : 4589.45
>   clflush size  : 64
>   cache_alignment   : 64
>   address sizes : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>   power management:

**What does this indicate, does my processor have 20 vcores or 40 vcores?**

Comment: Your machine obviously has 2 of these processors, each supplying 20 virtual cores for a total of 40 on 2x10 physical ones for a total of 20.

Comment: @EugenRieck why not post this as an answer? Seems like this answers the question perfectly.

Comment: @shanmuga - Your output shows no evidence that there are 40 virtual cores.

Comment: @EugenRieck how can I confirm if my system has two processors?

Comment: @Ramhound I get the same output is repeated 40 times with different processor number.

Comment: @shanmuga - Open the case and use visual verification.

Comment: @Ramhound That is not possible as this is a cloud server. Is there any way to check the same from command line?

Comment: dmesg? dmidecode, ...

Comment: @shanmuga - You should have mentioned that.  So this is a VPS?

Comment: [How-to determine the number of physical CPUs under both Windows and Linux](http://superuser.com/q/186682/241386), http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-find-the-number-of-physical-cpus-in-linux/, https://access.redhat.com/discussions/480953

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks. It looks like I have two of these processors (two different physical id) with 20 cores each.

Answer (score 1):

I'll summarize the comments by *@Eugen Rieck* and *Lưu Vĩnh Phúc*.

machine has 2 of these processors, each supplying 20 virtual cores for a total of 40 on 2x10 physical ones for a total of 20.

This can be confirmed by checking the `physical id` for each core.
In my case there are two distinct `physical id` 0 and 1, 20 cores in each.

[How-to determine the number of physical CPUs under both Windows and Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/186682/how-to-determine-the-number-of-physical-cpus-under-both-windows-and-linux)